# 1/N probability

Tags: code-golf, random, probability-theory

Because there are not enough simple [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenges:

Create an optionally unnamed program or function that, given (by any means) an integer 1 ≤ N ≤ 10000, outputs your language's True value with a pseudo-random probability of 1/N, False otherwise.

**Please note that the requirement for naming has been removed. Feel free to edit answers and scores accordingly.**

Some languages use 1 (or -1) and 0 for True and False, that is fine too.

**Example:**

Example input tests:

```
4 -> True
4 -> False
4 -> False
4 -> False
4 -> False
4 -> True
4 -> False
4 -> False
```

I.e. given 4; it returns True with a 25% chance and False with a 75% chance.

Comment: [Relevant meta post](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2194/31625)

Comment: Also [relevant meta post](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1325/42963).

Comment: As not all languages have built in "pseudorandomness" is it possible to get a seed as second argument? (E.g. Brainfuck)

Comment: @flawr use current millisecond...

Comment: @NBZ Brainf*** doesn't have that either

Comment: @SuperJedi224 Right. OK then; have a seed and optionally return a new seed. But only for languages that really don't have other options.

Comment: What's the largest `N` we have to accept?

Comment: @TobySpeight 10000.

Answer (score 27):

## MediaWiki templates with [ParserFunctions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ParserFunctions), 48 bytes

```
{{#ifexpr:1>{{#time:U}} mod {{{n}}}|true|false}}
```

Comment: Interesting choice of language :-)

Comment: Who the heck thought it would be sensible to add non-deterministic functions to MediaWiki templates!?

Comment: @immibis: well the non-determinism occurs from `#time`, probably to update the age of living people, etc.

Answer (score 15):

## Pyth, 3 bytes

```
!OQ
```

[Try it online](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%21OQ&input=5&debug=0)

Simple inversion of random choice from 0 to input

Amusingly in Pyth it is not possible to make a function that does this without `$` because Pyth functions are automatically memoized.

Comment: [It is possible.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=M!OQgQ.d0&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=4%0A4%0A4%0A4%0A4%0A4%0A4%0A4%0A4%0A4&debug=0)

Comment: @LeakyNun Ah right, I had forgotten about using the time for a random function, that's rather clever.

Comment: No, I just used time to de-memoize it.

Comment: I'm aware, I guess I just didn't word it well :P That said I don't think it would really work as a workaround for most submissions, if it were ever better than a full program for some reason. Taking the time as an argument probably isn't just allowed by default.

Comment: another one: `qhO` :p

Comment: @LeakyNun I believe this question predates the `Q` filling in at the end, as otherwise I would have answered `!O` ;)

Answer (score 12):

### CJam, 5 bytes

Gotta be quick with these ones...

```
rimr!
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=rimr!&input=5)

#### Explanation

```
ri e# Read input and convert to integer N.
mr e# Get a uniformly random value in [0 1 ... N-1].
!  e# Logical NOT, turns 0 into 1 and everything else into 0.
```

Comment: "*Gotta be quick with these ones...*" which is a reason to disagree with OP that "*there are not enough simple [tag:code-golf] challenges*". If FGITW is an issue, IMO it's too simple.

Answer (score 12):

### TI-BASIC, 4 bytes using [one byte tokens](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/one-byte-tokens/)

```
not(int(Ansrand
```

Determines if the integer part of the input times a random number in [0,1) is zero. `Ansrand<1` also works.

Comment: How... Is that four bytes?

Comment: @JanDvorak The first bytes is not(, the next is int(, the next is Ans, the next is rand. In general, graphing calculators do **not** use ASCII as their internal representation for programs.

Comment: @immibis In general, computers don't use ASCII either. This might be questionable, is there a meta discussion about that?

Comment: @Kroltan Yes; [this](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1541/how-to-score-ti-basic) is the meta discussion, and [this](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/one-byte-tokens) is the list of tokens that are one byte, which includes all four that I used.

Comment: @ThomasKwa thanks!

Answer (score 11):

### MATL, 5 bytes

Three different versions of this one, all length 5.

```
iYr1=
```

which takes an input (`i`), generates a random integer between 1 and that number (`Yr`), and sees if it it is equal to 1 (`1=`). Alternatively,

```
li/r>
```

make a 1 (`l`, a workaround because there is a bug with doing `1i` at the moment), take an input (`i`), divide to get 1/N (`/`), make a random number between 0 and 1 (`r`), and see if the random number is smaller than 1/N. Or,

```
ir*1<
```

take and input (`i`), and multiply by a random number between 0 and 1 (`r*`), and see if the result is smaller than 1 (`1<`).

In Matlab, not MATL, you can do this anonymous function

```
@(n)n*rand<1
```

for 12 bytes, which is used by doing `ans(5)`, for example.

Answer (score 10):

## Julia, <s>17</s> <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```julia
n->2>rand(1:n)
```

This is a function that generates a random integer between 1 and `n` and tests whether it's less than 2. There will be a 1/n chance of this happening, and thus a 1/n chance of returning `true`.

Saved 1 byte thanks to Thomas Kwa!

Answer (score 10):

## JavaScript ES6, 15 bytes

-5 bytes thanks to Downgoat.

```
x=>1>new Date%x
```

Based off (uses) of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66940/31957) answer's technique.

Comment: `new Date` can also work and might save a few bytes

Comment: @Downgoat Ah, right, Date randomness!

Answer (score 9):

## [Microscript II](https://github.com/SuperJedi224/Microscript-II), 3 bytes

```
NR!
```

Reads an integer `n`, generates a random integer between `0` and `n-1` (inclusive), then applies a boolean negation to that value.

Answer (score 8):

## [Candy](https://github.com/dale6john/candy), 2 bytes

```
Hn
```

*H* stands for *Heisen-double*

*n* stands for *not*

The 'n' is passed with the -i flag as numeric input.  Values left on the stack are printed on exit.

"Long" form:

```
rand   # number between 0 and pop()
not    # cast to int, invert non-zero to zero, and zero to one
```

Comment: I think you'd need to count `-i` as one byte.

Comment: basically the only way to pass numeric input is with the -i flag.  I guess only languages that read from stdin suffer no input specification penalty?

Comment: Well, if there were a generic input flag, or you just used regular CLAs to pass arguments, that would definitely be fine. It seems unfair that the datatype is being specified for free, though.

Comment: @ThomasKwa Should a function written in a dynamic language have to count the bytes to specify that the argument is an integer in the documentation? In `lambda x: random.random()<1/x` (ungolfed) it's also "specified for free" that the argument is a number.

Comment: @immibis Hmm, that's a good point. I guess trying to keep the rules for programs and functions the same should allow this, then. I'll make a post on meta.

Answer (score 7):

## R, <s>30</s> 22 bytes

#### code

```
cat(runif(1)<1/scan())          #new
f=function(N)cat(runif(1)<1/N)  #old
```

It generates a number from a uniform distribution (0 to 1) and should evaluate to true 1/n of the times.

Answer (score 7):

### Seriously, 3 bytes

```
,JY
```

`0` is falsey and `1` is truthy. [Try it online](http://seriouslylang.herokuapp.com/link/code=2c4a59&input=4)

Explanation:

```
,JY
,    get input
 J   push a random integer in range(0, input) ([0, ..., input-1])
  Y  logical not: push 0 if truthy else 1
```

Answer (score 6):

## APL, <s>6</s> 3 bytes

```
+=?
```

This is a function train that takes an integer and returns 1 or 0 (APL's true/false). We generate a random integer from 1 to the input using `?`, then check whether the input is equal to that integer. That results in a 1/input chance of true.

Saved 3 bytes thanks to Thomas Kwa!

Comment: @ThomasKwa I thought about some kind of train, but does that really count as a "named function" if assigned? I guess the "named" part is throwing me here since it's atypical.

Comment: @ThomasKwa Assignment of trains (and derived functions) is completely parallel to all other assignments.

Comment: @NBZ what do you mean by parallel?

Comment: @ThomasKwa Equivalent; behaving like any other function assignment.

Comment: I would use `⊢` instead of '+' because `+` means Conjugate for complex numbers. Of course it doesn't matter here, and `+` is the traditional identity (no-op) function, but now we have `⊢` (same). Other no-ops for scalars are: `⌷` (materialize), `⊃` (pick), `⊂` (enclose), `↑` (split), `↓` (mix), `∪` (unique), `∊` (enlist), `,` (ravel), `⍪` (table), `⌽` (reverse), `⊖` (reverse first), and `⍉` (transpose). Some change the scalar into a vector or matrix.

Answer (score 6):

## Japt, 6 bytes

```
1>U*Mr
```

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=MT5VKk1y&input=NA==)

`Mr` is equivalent to JS's `Math.random`. The rest is pretty obvious. I could probably add a number function that generates a random float between 0 and the number. When this happens, two bytes will be saved:

```
1>Ur    // Doesn't currently work
```

Alternate version:

```
1>Ð %U
```

`Ð` is equivalent to `new Date(`, and the Date object, when asked to convert to a number, becomes the current timestamp in milliseconds. Thus, this is entirely random, unless it is run multiple times per ms.

Answer (score 6):

## [PlatyPar](https://github.com/cyoce/PlatyPar), 3 bytes

```
#?!
```

`#?` gets a random number `[0,n)` where `n` is input.
`!` returns `true` if the number before it is `0`, else it returns `false`.

Using more recent features that were implemented (but unfortunately for me not committed) before this question was asked I can get it down to 2 with `~!`
[Try it online](https://rawgit.com/cyoce/PlatyPar/master/page.html?code=%7E%21)!

Answer (score 6):

## [Marbelous](https://github.com/marbelous-lang/docs/blob/master/spec-draft.md), 21 bytes

```
}0    # takes one input n
--    # decrements n
??    # random value from range 0..n (inclusive)
=0?0  # push right if not equal to 0, fall through otherwise | convert to zero
++    # increment | no-op
{0//  # output | push left
```

I've taken `0` to be falsey and `1` to be truthy, though there is no real reason for that seeing as Marbelous doesn't really have an if. More Marbelousy would be output to `{0` for true and `{>` for false. This would look like this:

```
}0
--
??
=0{>
{0
```

But I'm not sure that's valid.

Comment: I'd be up for a meta discussion on this. Short version of my view: outputting a value to a different output is equivalent to having different output tuples in another language. If (nil,1) and (1,nil) can be your truthy and falsey values in another language, then {0 vs {> should be allowed in Marbelous.

PS: your {> version won't exit because you never fill the other output.

Comment: @Sparr it will exit due to inactivity, no?

Comment: You're right. I feel dumb.

Answer (score 5):

## Java, 43 bytes

```
boolean b(int a){return a*Math.random()<1;}
```

Comment: `a->a*Math.random()<1` is shorter.

Comment: Should specify "Java 7 or earlier".

Comment: @corsiKlauseHoHoHo This works in Java 8 as well though

Comment: Of course it does - but it's not golfed for Java 8, which would use lambdas to save space. By that logic, all Java answers are also Groovy answers, but Groovy is always the same or smaller because it has shortcuts that Java doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

## C, 24 bytes

```
f(n){return!(rand()%n);}
```

Comment: I've rolled back OP's edit removing the first 4 characters. It's nice to have bytes reduced, but to me, having the `return`without the `f(n)` doesn't make any sense syntactically.

Comment: @insertusernamehere  `rand()%n` is a standard way of getting a random number in the range `0..n-1`. You are correct, it does rely on  `n` being much smaller than `RAND_MAX` but there is no upper limit for `n` mentioned in the question. An alternative approach would be to do a reject and re-roll on all numbers from `n` to RAND_MAX but it would be hopelessly inefficient at small `n`.

Answer (score 5):

## ><>, 27 + 3 for -v = 30 bytes

Here is a not-uniform-at-all solution where I mod N the sum of 15876 random picks of 0 or 1 :

```
0"~":*>:?vr%0=n;
1-$1+$^-1x
```

N must be input on the stack with -v flag, output is 0 for falsey and 1 for truthy.

A much smarter and uniform solution that work for 1/2^N instead :

```
4{:?!v1-}:">"$2p:"x"$3p:"^"$4p1+:">"$3p1+!
   ^1<
0n;
1n;>
```

For an input 3 you've got 1/8 chances of getting 1 and 7/8 of getting 0.

Explanation :

I append as much `x` as needed on the 4th line and surround them with directions so there is only two ways out of the `x`: either the falsey output or the next `x`. If all `x` go in the right direction, the last one will route to the truthy output.

For example for N=5, the final codespace is the following :

```
4{:?!v1-}:">"$2p:"x"$3p:"^"$4p1+:">"$3p1+!
   ^1<
0n; > > > > >
1n;>x>x>x>x>x>
    ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
```

Comment: While it's true you can't get a perfect distribution for arbitrary N, neither can anyone else using a PRNG. You could loop through an x a few times to get a bunch of random bits, assemble them into an int I, then use I%N as your random value.

Comment: @Sparr edited my answer but I feel like using a big number of iteration will 'average out' the resulting integer, making the output heavily tend toward `(iterNum/2)%N`. I don't think using a lower number would be a solution either. Did I maybe not quite understood you, or would you have any further idea to better the solution?

Comment: instead of adding 15000 bits together, produce just 32 bits and concatenate them, giving you a uniformly distributed 32-bit random integer. mod that.

Comment: @Sparr that seems better indeed, even if I've no idea why ;) That'll cost much more bytes (><> sucks for byte operations & base conversion) but I'll change my answer this evening (CEST).

Comment: you can concatenate bits by multiplying by two and adding: r=0; for(0..32) r=r*2+randbit;

Answer (score 4):

### Mathematica, <s>18</s> 16 bytes

```
#RandomReal[]<1&
```

Basic solution. The unnamed `Function` creates a random number in [0, 1), multiplies it by its argument, and checks if it is still less than 1.

Answer (score 4):

## Python, 42 bytes

```python
import random
lambda n:1>random.random()*n
```

*Edit*: Removed the `time.time()` answer because of the distribution.

Comment: For `random`, it's worth doing `from random import*` to save on `random.`. Not for `time` though.

Comment: Random numbers generated by modulo division are [not uniformly distributed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984974/why-do-people-say-there-is-modulo-bias-when-using-a-random-number-generator).

Comment: @TrangOul That's a good point; for larger `n` the effect could be noticeable. I think `1>time.time()%1*n` could work.

Comment: @TrangOul I presume you know the difference between `rand` in C, and `time.time` in Python... One obvious feature of the latter is that *it returns the current time*, which is unbounded, so that `time.time()%n` has a uniform distribution (over long enough periods of time) for any `n`.

Answer (score 4):

### [TeaScript](https://esolangs.org/wiki/TeaScript), 3 bytes

```
!N×
```

[Try it here.](http://vihanserver.tk/p/TeaScript/#?code=%22!N%C3%97%22&inputs=%5B%224%22%5D&opts=%7B%22int%22:false,%22ar%22:false,%22debug%22:false,%22chars%22:false,%22html%22:false%7D)

#### Explanation

```
 N  maps to Math.rand which is a utility function that returns an integer
    between `arg1` and `arg2` or `0` and `arg1` if only one argument is
    provided.
  × is expanded to `(x)`, where `x` is initialised with the value provided
    in the input boxes; × represents byte '\xd7'
!   negate the result, 0 results in true, anything else false
```

Comment: How does seven chars add up to 6 bytes? And is the (R) a (single byte) ANSI char?

Comment: @NBZ, haha! I think I lied... I blame hangover... I'll update now as I'm going to change the mechanism to a more straightforward one that I've just noticed! In this current version the `®` represents the char `'\xae'` so is just one byte. :)

Answer (score 4):

## Fuzzy Octo Guacamole, 10 bytes

```
^-!_[0]1.|
```

Explanation:

```
^-!_[0]1.|

^          # Get input.
 -         # Decrement, so we can append <ToS> zeros and a 1 to the stack.
  !        # Set loop counter.
   _       # Pop, since we are done with the input.
    [      # Start loop
     0     # Push 0
      ]    # End for loop. We have pushed input-1 0s to the stack.
       1   # Push a single 1 to the stack.
        .  # Switch stacks
         | # Pick a random item from the inactive stack, which has n-1 falsy items and 1 truthy item, so the truthy probability is 1/n.
           # (implicit output)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 14

Function

```
->n{rand(n)<1}
```

Program is slightly longer

```
p rand(gets.to_i)<1
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org),  <s>10</s>  8 bytes

```perl6
!(^*).pick
#  ^- The * is the argument
```

This code creates a Range from 0 up-to but excluding the input `*`. It then `pick`s one at random and the `!` returns True when it receives a `0`.

```perl6
1>*.rand
# ^- The * is the argument
```

This takes the input `*` and multiplies it by a random Num from `0..^1` then returns True if it was smaller than `1`.

```perl6
# store it in a lexical code variable for ease of use
my &code = 1>*.rand;

die "never dies here" unless code 1;

for ^8 { say code 4 }
```

```perl6
False
True
False
False
False
True
False
False
```

Answer (score 3):

### C#, <s>56</s> 45 bytes

Thanks to, pinkfloydx33 it's 45 now.

```
bool b(int n){return new Random().Next(n)<1;}
```

#### Old 56 bytes

Generates random positive integer bigger or equal to 0 and smaller than `n` and checks if it's smaller than `1` and return comparison result.

```
bool a(int n){Random r=new Random();return r.Next(n)<1;}
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Unfortunately, this submission doesn't work, because `Random.Next(k)` returns an integer `k` such that `0 <= k < n`. By changing the condition to `<1`, it will be correct. In addition, the use of a [lambda expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) may get your code shorter.

Comment: @Mego Sure, thank you for comment. I made it `0 < k <= n` and it should be like you said. I'll correct it immediately.

Comment: Use `var r` saves three. Or if c#6, `bool a(int n) => new Random().Next(n)<1;` for 41. Though not sure if initializing a new `Random` per method call will work properly as far as distribution?

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 22 bytes

```
<?=2>rand(1,$argv[1]);
```

Reads `n` from command line, like:

```
$ php probability.php 4
```

Outputs   (`false` is cast to an empty string in PHP) or `1` (in case of `true`).

Answer (score 3):

## Prolog (SWI), 24 bytes

**Code:**

```
p(N):-X is 1/N,maybe(X).
```

**maybe(+P)** is a function which succeeds with probability **P** and fails with probability **1-P**

**Example:**

```
p(4).
false

p(4).
false

p(4).
true
```

Answer (score 3):

### PowerShell, 25 Bytes

```
!(Random -ma($args[0]--))
```

The [`Get-Random` function](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849905.aspx) when given a `-Ma`ximum parameter `n` returns a value from the range `[0,n)`. We leverage that by subtracting 1 from our input `$args[0]`, so we're properly zero-indexed, and get a random value. Precisely `1/n`th of the time, this value will be `0`, so when we Boolean-not it with `!` it will return `True`. The other times will return `False`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Scratch](http://scratch.mit.edu), 63 bytes

[Try it online!](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/92127040) 
Picture: 
[image: greenflag;ask;say<rand(1)to(answer)=1>]

[Scratchblocks](http://scratchblocks.github.io/#when%20gf%20clicked%0Aask%5B%5Dand%20wait%0Asay%3C(pick%20random(1)to(answer))%3D%5B1%5D%3E) code:

```
when gf clicked
ask[]and wait
say<(pick random(1)to(answer))=[1
```

Comment: Uh oh my golf is longer than Java D:

Answer (score 3):

### J, 3 bytes

```
0=?
```

This is a monadic fork that takes an argument on the right. Similarly to APL, ? generates a random integer; however, J arrays are zero-based. So we compare to 0 instead of to the input.

Answer (score 3):

### [Minkolang 0.14](https://github.com/elendiastarman/Minkolang), 7 bytes

```
1nH1=N.
```

[Try it here.](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=%24l%5B14H1%3D%5D%24%2BN%2E&input=4)

#### Explanation

```
1          Pushes 1
 n         Takes number from input
  H        Pops b,a and pushes a random integer between a and b, inclusive
   1=      1 if equal to 1, 0 otherwise
     N.    Output as number and stop.
```

Answer (score 2):

### Perl, <s>18</s> 12 bytes

```perl
$_=1>rand$_
```

That is 11 bytes + 1 for the `-p` commandline argument.
Save in a file (any name, say, `16.pl`) and run as: `echo 4 | perl -p 16.pl`.
It will print an empty line for false, and 1 for true.

As a function: **18 bytes**

```perl
sub f{1>rand$_[0]}
```

Comment: Would it still be valid if "sub f" was removed? (Updated OP: Naming is not required anymore.)

Answer (score 2):

## , 3 chars / 6 bytes

```
!⁇ï
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter.html?eval=true&input=4&code=!%E2%81%87%C3%AF)</kbd>

The punctuation is strong with this one.

Answer (score 2):

## Racket, 21 bytes

```
(λ(x)(=(random x)0))
```

Answer (score 2):

## Reng v.3.3, noncompeting, 6 bytes

```
iu0en~
```

`i` takes input, `u` pushes a random integer in `[0,i)`, `0e` checks if the value is `e`qual to `0`, `n` outputs that value, and `~` terminates the program.

[Try it here!](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/)

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), <s>99</s> <s>98</s> <s>96</s> <s>95</s> <s>92</s> <s>90</s> 84 bytes

```
<vp90:g80<p80 &
v?v>v>9g1-:0`|
0^1-:0v\g80:$<
>v<10^ +*2p90<
@>\^`$`  >!.
 v  _^>  |
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcsxDkBAEEbhfk7xS0RByKBhMxkOImsjYTvRmMrdF90rvrftx33GPSWxa2QXB5ZrYBRkk6npGNvacXiI/R@2fMDlQmrSskdVdt8lNOviQx4AzRqCAatX4EmpfwE)

This deserves a separate spot from my other answer, as I did this from scratch.

This generates an integer (**x**) in the range **[0,2^n)** using random binary digits, then redoes the program if **x>=n** (Actually by checking **!(n>x)**, because befunge). Then, it tests if **x=0**, outputting the result.

Any ways to knock off bytes are wanted!

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5, 10 bytes

A subroutine:

```
{1>rand@_}
```

It takes input as a list of `1`s of the appropriate length.

[Hat-tip.](/a/66983)

Answer (score 1):

### [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 44 + 3 = 47 bytes

```
&v<
0x1v
?^0\l&:&-
1=?\2*+l
?!v\:&:&(
n;~>0=
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X63MhsugwrCMyz7OICZHzUpNl8vQ1j7GSEs7h8tesSzGCiikwZVnXWdnYPv//3/dMgVTAA), or watch it at the [fish playground](https://fishlanguage.com/playground)!

Input is taken on the stack, with the `-v` flag (hence the +3 bytes). Unlike the [other ><> answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67041/66104), this has a theoretically correct distribution, not just an approximately correct one (assuming the pseudo-random stuff behind the scenes is uniform).

Randomness is tricky in ><>: the only non-deterministic instruction is `x`, which sets the fish's direction randomly from four choices.

If you want a uniform random number from 1 to *N* but you only have a (fair) *m*-sided die, where *m* > *N*, you can do it by rolling the die, checking if the result is in the right range, and re-rolling if it isn't until you get a number between 1 and *N*. There's a probability of exactly 0 that you'll keep rolling the die forever without end, and the result you get (if the process terminates) is uniformly distributed. Also, if 1 < *m* < *N*, you can simulate an *m*<sup>*k*</sup>-sided die by rolling it *k* times, and you can make *m*<sup>*k*</sup> larger than *N* by picking *k* large enough. Thus you can simulate any rational probability using any die with more than 1 side (if you don't mind a vanishingly small chance of rolling the die forever).

This program rolls a 2<sup>*N*</sup>-sided die, by getting *N* random 1s or 0s and reading them in binary. The number 2<sup>*N*</sup> is always bigger than *N* for *N* ≥ 1, although it's usually a LOT bigger, so for large *N* you'll be waiting a while. TIO handles up to about *N* = 16.

Comment: The idea of using a random number in the range of `[1,2^n]` definitely works in other languages, (e.g. my Befunge answer)

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), <s>185</s> <s>171</s> <s>169</s> <s>142</s> <s>125</s> <s>124</s> <s>121</s> <s>118</s> <s>116</s> <s>113</s> 124 bytes

```
 &v>:00pv _v>v>\v
 > ^<  v?v:$1-+ :
@g:    1^2-1^   _$v>g`| @.0_1.
.$1    >v<1-\2*v+1<   >00g-^
 ^-     >\^>^>^>:00^  >
^#_#^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY2xCsMwEEN3f4UgJkODzV1GY675EHMugdRb6dKb@u@uXWmReCCd1/PzalfvWE0S0dtQTUyKOQg0A3a35DlsSO5oCUOse2AdoXqT9vjiiFQ5uuh5YrHMoew32zjPStSCOmjAnxaV6fE1JsTpUhftnYl@)

This uses the exact same strategy as [this ><> answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/148634/55550) (generate an integer in the range `[1,2^n]` by generating `n` random binary digits then converting it, then try again if the resulting integer is outside of the range `[1,n]`), but with two modifications:

- Separate case for `n=1`
- The binary digits are at first generated with `1`s and `2`s, since Befunge pops `0` off of the stack when empty. After the digits are generated, they are decremented to their normal binary and converted to an integer in place.

This is surprisingly fast!

Anything that will reduce the bytecount are welcome, considering I'm not a good befunge-golfer (especially when it comes to `g` and `p`)

I apparently am horrible at reading directions, as I [originally](https://tio.run/##HYwxCsMwFEN3n0IQk6HBwT@jMb85iPkugdRb6VJNvbvrVFrEE9JxPj@vdvaOmZpifBOVSi10UFgGeGfyEhYkt7eEIbEtiI1QPbU9vm71cnFlllC2GxfJ2NfsYAH/opheHv9jps6mOlnvEuMP) only outputted a random integer in the range `[1,n]` >_<.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
XỊ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/i4e6u/xWGBgaH2x81rfn/3wQA) (contains a footer that runs the program 100 times and reports the results)

I had to triple-check to make sure that Jelly wasn't here yet; it's a popular language, after all. But it turns out it wasn't.

`X` picks a random element from a list. Because it's at the start of the program but requires an input, it'll implicitly take the first command line argument as input. Most commands, when they expect a number but are given a list, convert the number into a range from 1 to that number; thus, for example, an input of 4 will pick a random element from [1, 2, 3, 4]. (Actually, Jelly has a special case to optimise this internally by not constructing the list.) Note that for an input of *n*, this means that there's a 1 in *n* chance of picking 1 as our element.

Once we have our element, we run `Ị` on it. That's a test for a small value, i.e. no higher than 1 or smaller than -1. The only element that we can produce that matches this condition is 1, so we get an output of true (expressed as `1` in Jelly) with 1/n probability, and false (expressed as `0` in Jelly) the rest of the time. The output then gets printed implicitly.

(This submission also works as a function rather than a full program, exactly the same way; the implicit input is then taken from the function argument, and the implicit output used as the function's return value.)

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 15 bytes

```
INPUT N?!RND(N)
```

`RND(n)` generates a random number from `0` to `n-1`, so there's a `1/n` chance that it will be `0`. Then it just uses `!` (logical not) to convert this to a `1/n` chance of generating `1` (true), and prints the result.

Answer (score 1):

### [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg/), 6 bytes

```
¿~$%2<
```

Takes random number & input, modulos them and checks whether the result is less than 2.

Answer (score 0):

## [MY](https://bitbucket.org/zacharyjtaylor/my-language), 5 bytes

```
ω0x=←
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y638//98p0GF7aO2Cf///zcCAA)

### How it works:

Generates a random integer in the range `[0,n)`, then tests for equality with `0`.

Comment: I assume you meant [0,n-1] since [1,n] does not include 0.

Comment: Yes, thank you! Lol.

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 8 bytes

```
~rand 0=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v64oMS9FwcD2/38TAA)

Answer (score 0):

## J, 6 bytes

```
?&0:<%
```

### explanation

A J fork:

```
      ?&0:                <               %
NB. uniform float    is less than?    1 / input
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYpBCsIwEADvecVQjG0x1PUaWgQf4B9sm6WKGDD02Len0cMwh5lX1sTgEQr5ehTf29yaqqPWwdc4No8mY8K0RE5nGq2k5SIiHIq43zrSEtf3zBh4fOP6mX/Z8QzFlqj/O@8)

Answer (score 0):

## x86, 10 bytes

Apparently there's a fairly new instruction called [`rdrand`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RdRand) which makes this program pretty trivial.

Input in `ecx`, output in `ZF`. I consider one of x86's flags as a valid return value, which is arguably more useful than `setz` and returning in `eax`. It would've been very convenient if `div` set `ZF`.

```
5:  0f c7 f0                rdrand %eax
8:  31 d2                   xor    %edx,%edx
a:  f7 f1                   div    %ecx
c:  85 d2                   test   %edx,%edx
e:  c3                      ret
```

Comment: Treating as signed int saves 1 bytes (only work for small ecx but anyway old one too)

Answer (score 0):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 7 bytes

```
ISx*1(h
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/3zO4QstQA8gwAQA)

#### How it works

```
ISx*1(h

I        Take input as number
 Sx      Generate random number in [0,1)
   *     Multiply the two
    1(   Is it less than 1?
      h  Print the result as number and halt
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `!`, 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Lɼ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPUwlQzklQkMmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD00JmZsYWdzPSE=)

##### Explanation

```python
    # Implicit input
L   # Push [0..input)
 ɼ  # Take a random item
    # Logical NOT
    # (Check for != 0)
    # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
LΩ
```

Only `1` is truthy in 05AB1E, everything else is falsey, which is used to our advantage here.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f59zK//9NAA) or [try it online an infinite amount of times with additional 05AB1E-truthify (`==1`) check](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@oY965rZ7/fc6t/H9uxn9DAwA).

**Explanation:**

```python
L   # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input]
 Ω  # Pop and push a random integer from this list
    # (which is output implicitly as result)
```